# ASP.NET MVC plugins and AppDomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, appdomain

I had a need to develop ASP.NET MVC application where one or more assemblies are considered a plugin, these assemblies are loaded dynamically by ASP.NET during the initialization phase.

I've done that and everything is working pretty good my question is whether I should load them into their own AppDomain and is doing something like the example below make sense in this context?

```
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(asmName.Name, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, domainSetup, trustedPermissionSet);

Assembly assembly = domain.Load(asmName); //Assembly.Load(asmName);

BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly(assembly);
```

The reason I'm asking is I don't really know how the BuildManager handles the assemblies in ASP.NET, any clarification, pros and cons of this approach would be great.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the question in the [ASP.NET MVC forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1862072.aspx/1?ASP%20NET%20MVC%20plugins%20and%20AppDomain) and it seems like I got most of the information I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for link eyal, looked like frustrating discussion. To summarise then, asp.net MVC plugin architecture where http context has to cross appdomains won't work [confidently]?

Comment: Yeah, depends what you're doing there like he stated in his last reply. :)